# generating httptemplate (html) using python code

Tags: python, html, django, templates

I have used python so far only for simple applications. I want to create a html file using python code which I can use on web server. How can I create this template using Django?

Comment: -1 for not bothering to read the Django documentation. Templating is extensively covered in the tutorial and the full docs.

Answer (score 1):

you'll need an intro, take a look at this post http://elleestcrimi.me/2012/03/15/introduction-django-guestbook-application/
it walks you through creating a simple django app.
if there's something you can't understand there, you can comment on the blog post,
the owner is very helpful